# Autoscale Amazon Kinesis through Application Autoscaling or Lambda?

Tags: aws-lambda, autoscaling, amazon-kinesis, api-gateway, amazon-cloudwatch

I came across multiple solutions to autoscale kinesis datastreams through Amazon Cloudwatch and Lambda functions. Recently, AWS introduced another approach — Application autoscaling to scale applications like EMR, custom application like Kinesis etc through scaling policies, API Gateway and Lambda functions to autoscale.

I have been searching for hours but can not find which approach is better and why?

Why are we using API Gateway to invoke Lambda when we already can invoke lambda through SNS?

- **First approach** - Cloudwatch, SNS and Lambda: [Auto-scaling Kinesis streams with AWS Lambda | theburningmonk.com](https://theburningmonk.com/2017/04/auto-scaling-kinesis-streams-with-aws-lambda/)
- **Second approach** - Application autoscaling, API Gateway: [Scaling Amazon Kinesis Data Streams with AWS Application Auto Scaling | AWS Big Data Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/scaling-amazon-kinesis-data-streams-with-aws-application-auto-scaling/)

Can anyone help me understand the need of API Gateway in second approach and also which approach is better?

Comment: Same here. Did you already get the solution?